# Error in creating custom customer attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom, customer-attribute

I need to create customer custom attribute.

In `module.xml`

```
<sequence>           
       <module name="Magento_Customer"/>  
</sequence>
```

in upgrade schema `UpgradeSchema.php`

```
namespace  Namespace\Modulename\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements  UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
     private $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
                            ModuleContextInterface $context){
        $setup->startSetup();

            if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.4') < 0) {
            /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                Customer::ENTITY,
                'example1',
                [
                    'label' => 'Example Attribute',
                    'required' => 0,
                    'system' => 0, // <-- important, otherwise values aren't saved.
                                   // @see Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CustomerMetadata::getCustomAttributesMetadata()
                    'position' => 100
                ]
            );
            $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'example1')
                ->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer'])
                ->save();
        }


        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

I am getting error

> Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetu   p::__construct() must implement
>   interface Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDat   aSetupInterface,
>   instance of Magento\Setup\Module\Setup given, called in /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Abstrac
>   tFactory.php on line 93 and defined in
>   /vendor/magento
>   o/module-customer/Setup/CustomerSetup.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could ***not create a customer attribute*** using **magento schema files** both *`InstallSchema`* and UpgradeSchema.Need to use **data files** ***InstallData and UpgradeData***.

Because of in order create ***an attribute*** you should  inject *`Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory`*  on `__construct function of your class` and   **`Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup`** main class of  this factory class.

But this class  **`Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup`** class injects at `Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface` on it's __construct function.

And as you  use ***`Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface`*** and ***`Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface`***.

So it cannot **be  possible to**   get interface `Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface` at **`Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup`**.

And you can only use  `Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface` on data installdata and upgradedata file mean data installer file.

**Solution** is that you should use **UpgradeData.php** instead of **UpgradeSchema.php**

### Installer should be

```
<?php

namespace  Namespace\Modulename\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
/* irrelevant */
#use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
/* irrelevant */
#use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
/* add this */
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements  UpgradeDataInterface
{
     private $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
                            ModuleContextInterface $context){
        $setup->startSetup();

            if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.4') < 0) {
            /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                Customer::ENTITY,
                'example1',
                [
                    'label' => 'Example Attribute',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'default' => '0',
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => 0,
                    'system' => false, // <-- important, otherwise values aren't saved.
                                   // @see Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CustomerMetadata::getCustomAttributesMetadata()
                    'position' => 100
                ]
            );
           $example1Attribute =$customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'example1');
            $example1Attribut->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer']);
                $example1Attribute->save();
        }    
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, may i how to render it to admin page only? i don't want to frontend page have it, please help, thanks :3

Comment: But as per Magento docs, it says `installData` and `upgradeData` to install the sample data into the table whereas `installSchema` and `upgradeSchema` to be used to modify the table structure right? What is the reason behind it doesn't work for customer attribute?